# Adding multiple image views programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm basically trying to achieve drag&drop feature..

What i'm trying is that i provides sequence of images on the screen, if i click on any image available in `images` row that will be added to the `Mains screen`. But i'm getting problem that when i add new view into the `Main Screen` then all the other `views` also moved to top left corner.

Can you please tell me what is the problem...? Or kindly suggest me a tutorial or link where i can find solution.... or how to achieve this ?

I'm using `Framelayout`, So that i also achieve images overlapping...

[image]

This is the class in which all code is working:

```
public class drag extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnTouchListener
{
ImageView img1;
Button btn,btn2;
FrameLayout layout;
LayoutParams params;
ImageView im , im2, im3 ,im4;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.vg);
    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    im  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
    im.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    im.setOnTouchListener(this);
    im.setOnClickListener(this);

    btn  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn.setOnTouchListener(this);

    btn2  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn2.setOnTouchListener(this);

    params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            im2 = new ImageView(drag.this);
            Bitmap bm  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
            im2.setImageBitmap(bm);
            im2.setOnTouchListener(drag.this);
            im2.setOnClickListener(drag.this);
            layout.addView(im2, params);

        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Bitmap bm  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);                
            saveImage(bm);

        }
    });
}

public  void saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) 
{
    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), myBitmap, "mmsImage" , "mmsimage");       
}

int l, t, r, b;
int oldLeft, oldTop;
PointF p, curr;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) 
{

    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
    {           
        //status = START_DRAGGING;
        Log.i("status"," AAA dOWN");
        img1 = new ImageView(this);
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap mmsImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());

        img1.setImageBitmap(mmsImage);
        img1.setOnTouchListener(drag.this);
        img1.setOnClickListener(drag.this);

        oldLeft = (int)view.getLeft();
        oldTop = (int)view.getTop();

        p = new PointF(me.getRawX(), me.getRawY());


    }
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) 
    {
        Log.i("status"," AAA draging");

        int xDiff = (int)(me.getRawX() - p.x);
        int yDiff  = (int)(me.getRawY() - p.y);

        p.x = me.getRawX();
        p.y = me.getRawY();

        l = view.getLeft();
        t = view.getTop();
        r = view.getRight();
        b = view.getBottom();

        view.layout(l + xDiff, t + yDiff , r + xDiff, b + yDiff);

    }
    if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
    {
        Log.i("status"," AAA UP");
        //captureUserMove(view);
    } 

    return false;
}
```

}

Here is the XML :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/vg"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the code where you add the views. Otherwise, how are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Post the relevant code, please.

Comment: Please, think about this a little bit.  You use `params` to position the view but you don't show how`params` is constructed.  You add it to `layout`, and you don't show how that is instantiated.  Come on, please help us to help you....

Comment: @Simon thank you for your response... i've now added my complete code...

Answer (score 2):

You set `params`, but don't specify how to position the added view.  Try this:

In `onCreate()`

```
params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP; // you need this for margins to work
```

In the click listener:

```
// your x and y where you want the new view    
params.leftMargin = x;
params.topMargin = y;
```

Comment: Perhaps the most useless thing you can say in programming is "it didn't work".

Answer (score 0):

Putting

```
params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

inside

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
}
```

will work.